# Which bytes of video data refer to the current playback position

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media, mp4, media-source

I'm working with media source extensions to play a video in the browser.

My JavaScript program divides a video file in fragments of 1200 bytes.
The video is encoded in the following codec: video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2".
Giving a time X in seconds I want to find the corresponding first fragment that is needed to play the video at position X (Or a fragment that is near to but not after this position).
More concrete, I want to find out which fragment belongs to the time in the currentTime property of HTMLMediaElement.
The video file can be analysed beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a multitude of ways for the duration->fragment mapping to be specified in the mp4 file.

- The `subsegment index` (`sidx` for short) box defined in ISO/IEC 14496-12 associates bytes ranges from the input file with the corresponding durations.

Here is a snippet of a sidx box content:

```
subsegment 0 size 726463 dur 450450
subsegment 1 size 723260 dur 450450
subsegment 2 size 713278 dur 450450
subsegment 3 size 441644 dur 450450
... and so on ...
```

Finding the fragment for given time `X` is trivial.

- most `mp4` files don't have a `sidx` box but rather a `stsz` and `stts` boxes that map a series of samples (video or audio frames) to a duration + size. Here is and example:

stsz box:

```
sample 0 size 105222
sample 1 size 1554
sample 2 size 2153
```

stts box:

```
3 sample each with dur 512
```

The `stts` box give the duration for the samples defined in stsz

- there might be other ways. This list is not exhaustive